# Self homotopy equivalence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Given $X$, a simply connected CW-complex of finite type, ${\rm aut}(X)$ denotes the set of its **self homotopy equivalences**, that are maps $f: X\rightarrow X$ which admits a homotopy inverse (i.e., ${\rm aut}(X)$ is the set of automorphism of $X$ in the pointed homotopy category). ${\rm Baut}(X)$ denotes the associated classification space.

**Question:** Did we know any thing about the cases ${\rm Baut}(X)$ formal or ${\rm Baut}(X)$ coformal?

Comment: $\pi_0 aut(X)$ is the automorphism group of $X$ in the homotopy category.

Comment: I want to know if the formality of ${\rm Baut}(X)$ was already studied elsewhere

Comment: See http://people.sju.edu/~smith/pdf_files/factor3.pdf, "Rational Type of Classifying Spaces for Fibrations" by Samuel Bruce Smith.

Comment: Have you checked J.W.Rutter: Spaces of homotopy self-equivalences - a survey. Springer LNMA 1662 (1997)?

Comment: @MatthiasWendt: Thanks, I will do it right now

Comment: Indeed, Smith's paper suggested by Igor gave a lot of formality characterizations, but for $Baut_1(X)$, where $aut_1(X)$ denotes the identity component. I ask if there is any bridge between the formality of $Baut_1(X)$ and that of $Baut(X)$